# How do I unit test TanStack's queryClient

Tags: unit-testing, react-query, nock, tanstackreact-query

I'm trying to unit test Tanstack's queryClient and I am able to test queries and components, but not sure how I would go about testing the queryCache and mutationCache inside of the queryClient and to be quite honest, I don't have a clue as to where to start. My test suite is pinging the lines that have comments below.

```
`const queryClient = new QueryClient({
   defaultOptions: {},
   queryCache: new QueryCache({
     onError: (error) => handleError(error) //line to test
   }),
   mutationCache: new mutationCache({
     onError: (error) => handleError(error) //line to test 
   }),
 })`
```

Nothing, I don't even know where to start and I'm getting paralysis. Would I need to create a nock query and run an error there?

Comment: Why do you want to test an upstream library in isolation? They already have thousands of tests on their side.
If you want to test the `onError` code, your best bet would be to test a "real error" scenario in your application, e.g. by simulating a network error with `msw`, not trying to write a unit test to just trigger this line of code.

Comment: I gotta use nock but yeah you spurred an idea

Comment: I don't mind giving  you a checkmark if you place it as an answer. I don't have it finished yet, but because of you, I'll get there

Comment: No need for more points, happy you have a path now :)

Comment: appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't test the library. It has its own tests. Instead you should test your code to ensure that your `handleError` function behaves the way you expect, not that it's called correctly by tanstack-query